# Obtaining information passed into Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to see where the data's being called from. I'm not sure what 'Saved' is being referred to in the line below.

I have this line:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="a" onclick="showAndroidData('Saved');" />
```

Here is the main.js file:

```
$('#submit').bind('click', function(){

        var getfname = $('#fname').val();
        var getlname = $('#lname').val();

        if(getfname == ""){ 
            $('#fname').css('border', '3px solid yellow');
            return false;
        }
        if(getlname == ""){ 
            $('#lname').css('border', '3px solid yellow');
            return false;
        }
});

function showAndroidData(data) {

    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();

    var array = [fname, lname];

    Android.showData(array);
};
```

and the .HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mobile Web App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

        <div data-role="content">   
            <form action="#" method="post" name="justaform" id="justaform">
            <div id="pinfo" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><h3 id="formtitle">Enter Player Information</h3></legend>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="John" class="required" />

                    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Smith" class="required" />


                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <div id="submit-reset-buttons">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="c" onclick="showAndroidData('Saved');" />       
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.1.15.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But not exactly sure what 'Saved' is referring to? How is it obtaining these values inputted into the text fields?

Comment: 'Saved' is never used in the showAndroidData() function

Comment: Actually, the string `Saved` is not being used for anything as the variable `data` is never utilized inside the function `showAndroidData`. The rest is just two input elements and jQuery to retrieve their values.

Comment: For your other question, take a look at http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: `showAndroidData(data)` well it says `data` right there,

Comment: Got it thanks! Was a typo according to him which is why I was confused... thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it since it is not referenced anywhere. Don't pass that string to the function so you can improve code clarity...

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="a" onclick="showAndroidData();" />
```

then remove the `data` parameter...

```
function showAndroidData() {

    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname = $('#lname').val();

    var array = [fname, lname];

    Android.showData(array);
};
```